# Smart spreadsheet parsing (managing group sub-header and sum rows, etc)

Tags: r

Say you have a set of spreadsheets formatted like so:

[image]

Is there an established method/library to parse this into R without having to individually edit the source spreadsheets?  The aim is to parse header rows and dispense with sum rows so the output is the raw data, like so:

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4            7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
5            6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
6            6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
7            5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor
8            6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
9            5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
10           7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica
```

I can certainly hack a tailored solution to this, but wondering there is something a bit more developed/elegant than `read.csv` and a load of logic.

Here's a reproducible demo csv dataset (can't assume an equal number of lines per group..), although I'm hoping the solution can transpose to `*.xlsx`:

```
,Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width
,,,,
Setosa,,,,
1,5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2
2,4.9,3,1.4,0.2
3,4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2
Mean,4.9,3.23,1.37,0.2
,,,,
Versicolor,,,,
1,7,3.2,4.7,1.4
2,6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5
3,6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5
Mean,6.77,3.17,4.7,1.47
,,,,
Virginica,,,,
1,6.3,3.3,6,2.5
2,5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9
3,7.1,3,5.9,2.1
Mean,6.4,3,5.67,2.17
```

Comment: I think there's something of a Hadleyverse gap here - i.e. a "grammar of parsing spreadsheets" to complement dplyr..

Answer (score 2):

There is a variety of ways to present spreadsheets so it would be hard to have a consistent methodology for all presentations. However, it is possible to transform the data once it is loaded in R. Here's an example with your data. It uses the function `na.locf` from package `zoo`.

```
x <- read.csv(text=",Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width
,,,,
Setosa,,,,
1,5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2
2,4.9,3,1.4,0.2
3,4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2
Mean,4.9,3.23,1.37,0.2
,,,,
Versicolor,,,,
1,7,3.2,4.7,1.4
2,6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5
3,6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5
Mean,6.77,3.17,4.7,1.47
,,,,
Virginica,,,,
1,6.3,3.3,6,2.5
2,5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9
3,7.1,3,5.9,2.1
Mean,6.4,3,5.67,2.17", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(zoo)
x <- x[x$X!="Mean",] #remove Mean line
x$Species <- x$X     #create species column
x$Species[grepl("[0-9]",x$Species)] <- NA  #put NA if Species contains numbers
x$Species <- na.locf(x$Species)             #carry last observation if NA
x <- x[!rowSums(is.na(x))>0,]               #remove lines with NA

   X Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
3  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     Setosa
4  2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     Setosa
5  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     Setosa
9  1          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 Versicolor
10 2          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 Versicolor
11 3          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 Versicolor
15 1          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  Virginica
16 2          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  Virginica
17 3          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  Virginica
```

Comment: OK I do like `na.locf`. Otherwise this is still "read.csv and a load of logic", but admittedly quite elegant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently did something similar. Here was my solution:

```
iris <- read.csv(text=",Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width
,,,,
Setosa,,,,
1,5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2
2,4.9,3,1.4,0.2
3,4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2
Mean,4.9,3.23,1.37,0.2
,,,,
Versicolor,,,,
1,7,3.2,4.7,1.4
2,6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5
3,6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5
Mean,6.77,3.17,4.7,1.47
,,,,
Virginica,,,,
1,6.3,3.3,6,2.5
2,5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9
3,7.1,3,5.9,2.1
Mean,6.4,3,5.67,2.17", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

First I used a which splits at an index.

```
split_at <- function(x, index) {
N <- NROW(x)
s <- cumsum(seq_len(N) %in% index)
unname(split(x, s))
}
```

Then you define that index using:

```
iris[,1] <- stringr::str_trim(iris[,1])
index <- which(iris[,1] %in% c("Virginica", "Versicolor", "Setosa"))
```

The rest is just using purrr::map_df to perform actions on each data.frame in the list that's returned. You can add some additional flexibility for removing unwanted rows if needed.

```
split_at(iris, index) %>% 
.[2:length(.)] %>% 
purrr::map_df(function(x) {
  Species <- x[1,1]
  x <- x[-c(1,NROW(x) - 1, NROW(x)),]
  data.frame(x, Species = Species)
})
```